# Regex - Special Character After 1 or more digits

Tags: regex

I'm fairly rough with regex and I need to have a special character after number. If there is multiple numbers then the special character would have to be after the entire group.

Special Characters include !@#$%^&*()

abcd1 not valid

abcd1# valid

abcd11# valid

What I currently have checks if the string is between 5 and 30 characters and contains a number

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{5,30}$
```

Comment: What's a "special character"?

Comment: Added it in the question !@#$%^&*()

Comment: Try \S+\d+[!@#$%^&*()]
\S+ says all chars which are not a whitespace and a minimum of 1 char
\d+ says numbers and a mimimum of 1
if this needs to be the end of the line add a $ at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
'\d+[!@#$%^&*()]'
```